# Angular: translate function not reachable from other component

Tags: angularjs, angular-i18n

in my Angular App I have a main component A and a sub component B loaded by lazy loading.

In this sub component B I have the following functions:

```
  translator(){

    this.translate.use('de');
  }

  checkText(){

    console.log('check text works!')
  }
```

And, if I call this 2 functions from A by:

```
  this.administrationMainComponent.checkText();

  this.administrationMainComponent.translator();
```

Only the check text works.

1) Sure is not a problem of translator in B itself (if I execute it from the constructor of B, it works perfectly);

2) Sure, is not a problem about Injectable or something similar, because the check text works perfectly if I call it from A

How can I solve the problem and execute correctly translator from A?

EDIT: Also by this way it doesn't work

```
 translator = () => {

    console.log('check translator text!');
    this.translate.use('de');
 }
```

Comment: I assume you have tried with a console.log in translator too? If so, and it doesn't hit it , use the chrome developer tools to put a breakpoint and see what happens.

Comment: First, thank you very much. You right, I tried it and the console.log into translator function works fine but not the translator instruction itself. And, in Chrome dev tool, no error or warning. Thank you, is very important.

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you have the german language file loaded?

Comment: Yes but as already told the translator itself is NOT a problem beacuse in the entire app it works fine. I.E., if I call this function from the lazy loaded component it self, at the opening the language change and the text appears. The problem is only if I try to change it from the main selector component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://medium.com/@lopesgon/translate-angular-4-with-ngx-translate-and-multiple-modules-7d9f0252f139

This is the solution: put the translator part of the module in an external shared module and shared the same from it.